# Can't set default value to useState

Tags: reactjs

I am new in React and do not understand why this lines doesn't work:

```
const { showProjects, setShowProjects } = useState(true);
  console.log(showProjects);
```

Currently it returns `undefined` when I am trying to make it return `true` for example.

Comment: it should be an array, not an object. you can see the docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: [showProjects, setShowProjects] should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

```
const [showProjects, setShowProjects] = useState(true);
  console.log(showProjects);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define hooks const this way:

const [ showProjects, setShowProjects ] = useState(true);

See [useState docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#state-hook)

Comment: Thank you! Will check it again :)